# How to set a variable depending of a SQL check in TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

There is a Database-table "tt_content" check in my TypoScript code. 
Depending on whether the CONTENT is empty or not, I want to set a variable VAR to "empty" or "full". 
Is it possible?

```
MIDCONTENT= CONTENT
MIDCONTENT{
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.where = colPos = 0  
}
```

I allready have found a way to set the MIDCONTENT itselfe to empty, by doing

```
MIDCONTENT= CONTENT
MIDCONTENT{
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.where = colPos = 0  

  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.value = empty
}
```

But what i need, is setting another variable, and i need to check the full state either.

Comment: Maybe you are asking the wrong people. It's a mailing-list there. Typoscript isn"t really a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**untested**

If i unterstand you right, you want to add an class="full" to ATagParams only if there are tt_content records in that page?

```
NO.ATagParams.append = TEXT
NO.ATagParams.append {
  value = class="full"
  # Space before and after
  noTrimWrap = | | |
  if.isTrue.numRows {
    table = tt_content
    select {
      where = colPos = 0 
      # the uid of the page, is the pid of the tt_content elements
      pidInList.field = uid
    }
  }
}
```

If there are no records on that page, numRows will return 0, so if.isTrue will returns false and the TEXT object will not be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like :

```
enable = 1
enable.if.isTrue.field = MIDCONTENT
```

I don't have my typo3 installation with me to test. Plus, you didn't really described what you want to do... More details can help you a lot more.

Comment: The task is: <br>
to assign class="full" to a variable, if column 0 is not empty.
In java it would be: <br> <code>if(colPos0!= ""){NO.ATagParams= class="full" }</code>

Comment: I have tried:
stdWrap.if.isTrue.cObject=TEXT  stdWrap.if.isTrue.cObject.value=dir   - it did not work

Comment: Check this link : http://www.nicolaskuttler.com/post/change-template-if-content-exists-in-typo3/

Make youre MIDCONTENT a COA, put youre code in 10 with a isTrue, copie with 20 < .10 and change the 20's isTrue for a isFalse